# How to disable the Charging and Network identification in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I want to disable the Charging and Network identification in Windows phone emulator.. Is there any way to do this ?

Moreover i have a doubt that can we disable it using the xaml or c# code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the information you mention is in the "system tray" - this can be hidden (if you're targeting version 7.1 of the SDK or above) by simply adding `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"` to your `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>` element